# Excluir TEdit criado em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

No clique do botão eu crio alguns `Edits`... Até aí tudo funciona normalmente, porém quando tento excluir os `edits` criados clicando em outro botão, nem todos são excluídos.

Ex. criei 10 campos `edits`, quando clico para excluir todos de uma só vez, apenas 5 são excluídos. Seguem os códigos (inclusão e exclusão respectivamente):

```
for x := 0 to (NumReg -1) do
begin
  ArrayEdit[x] := TEdit.Create(Self);
  ArrayEdit[x].Parent := Self;
  ArrayEdit[x].Name := 'edtPreco'+ IntToStr(x+1);
  ArrayEdit[x].Left := 265;
  ArrayEdit[x].Top := 300 + x * 25;
end;

var Component: TComponent; 
begin 
  for Component in Self do 
    if Component is TEdit then
      TEdit(Component).Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    If (Components[i] is TEdit) then
      TEdit(Components[i]).Destroy;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
while (Form1.ComponentCount > 1) do 
begin
  if (Form1.Components[0] is TEdit) then
    TEdit(Form1.Components[0]).Free;
end;
```

Comment: Se o cara tiver um `TButton` no `Form1`, já vai entrar em um loop infinito.
E outra questão é que dessa forma, não vai destruir o ultimo `TEdit`, pois o `ComponentCount` vai ser `= 1`, e não `> 1`

Comment: cara testei aqui rapidão esse código e com 0 dava access violation somente com 1 deu certo e outra se o componente é Edit que vai deletar

Comment: Vi que no seu código vc usa destroy estava com uma dúvida sobre isso, a algum tempo estava com problema de memory leak usando free, passei a usar destroy e resolveu, saberia me explicar a diferença entre os dois? procurei muito na internet mas não encontrei nenhuma resposta.